# How is this bash snippet working?

Tags: linux, bash

A usual check if a binary exists:

```
if hash gdate 2>/dev/null; then
    gdate "$@"
else
    date "$@"
fi
```

When ran from the commandline:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-saucy-32:~$ hash gdate 2>/dev/null
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-saucy-32:~$ echo $?
1
```

This means that if I run the script, date will be called since I don't have gdate on my system.

So, this would mean that the snippet above is something like this?

```
if 1; then
  gdate "$@"
else
  date "$@"
fi
```

I thought that 1 evaluates to true in bash, so, shouldn't the if branch be chosen, instead of the else? Could someone break down this snippet for me?

Comment: Start your shell script temporarily with `#!/bin/bash -vx` (then remove `-vx` once you are happy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unix systems, an exit status of 0 is success; anything else is failure.

This is independent of what goes on inside `test` operations.  The `test` command too returns (exits with a status of) 0 when the condition is true and 1 when it is false.

---

#### Comments and Answers

[pfnuesel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945981/pfnuesel) asked:

> Is this always true? Isn't there C-like evaluation of true/false in some specific cases?

*Specify a counter-example...Yes, I believe it is always true. Run `[ "$var" != "value" ]; echo $?` or `[[ $var != value ]]; echo $?` or similar command combinations and see what you get.*

> `i=0; (( i++ )); echo $?`

Hmmm...interesting; that definitely made me pause for thought. It complicates things, but (assuming you agree that it produces 1 from `echo $?`), I think that means that the `((` command is being careful to invert the logic. If you run a test on the `((` command for various values of `$i`, you will find that when the expression evaluates to 0 (as it does in your example because it is a post-increment), then the exit status is 1, which is false, but otherwise, the exit status is 0, which is true. This applies to `bash` and `ksh` (and I think that is `bash` following `ksh`).

I used this script to help clarify things to myself:

```
for start in {-3..3}
do
    for shell in bash ksh sh
    do
        output=$($shell -c "i=$start;"' if (( i++ )); then echo $? true $i; else echo $? false $i; fi')
        printf "%-4s %4s %s %-5s %s\n" $shell "[$start]" $output
    done
done
```

Output:

```
bash [-3] 0 true  -2
ksh  [-3] 0 true  -2
sh   [-3] 0 true  -2
bash [-2] 0 true  -1
ksh  [-2] 0 true  -1
sh   [-2] 0 true  -1
bash [-1] 0 true  0
ksh  [-1] 0 true  0
sh   [-1] 0 true  0
bash  [0] 1 false 1
ksh   [0] 1 false 1
sh    [0] 1 false 1
bash  [1] 0 true  2
ksh   [1] 0 true  2
sh    [1] 0 true  2
bash  [2] 0 true  3
ksh   [2] 0 true  3
sh    [2] 0 true  3
bash  [3] 0 true  4
ksh   [3] 0 true  4
sh    [3] 0 true  4
```

Interestingly, the POSIX [shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) syntax recognizes the possibility of `((` as a command:

> If a character sequence beginning with "`((`" would be parsed by the shell as an arithmetic expansion if preceded by a '`$`', shells which implement an extension whereby "`((expression))`" is evaluated as an arithmetic expression may treat the "`((`" as introducing as an arithmetic evaluation instead of a grouping command. A conforming application shall ensure that it separates the two leading '`(`' characters with white space to prevent the shell from performing an arithmetic evaluation.

Comment: Is this always true? Isn't there c-like evaluation of true/false in some specific cases?

Comment: Specify a counter-example...Yes, I believe it is always true.  Run `[ "$var" != "value" ]; echo $?` or `[[ $var != value ]]; echo $?` or similar command combinations and see what you get.

Comment: `i=0; (( i++ )); echo $?`

Comment: @pfnuesel: Interesting.  See my update to my answer.  Thank you for asking!

Answer (score 2):

The code works as you've analyzed.  Only issue is your last statement.  In bash, true ("success") is a zero exit status, non-true ("failure") is non-zero.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

So, in bash, if a command exits with zero, conditionals will see that as the "true" branch.  If a command exits with anything other than zero, conditionals will treat that as the "false" branch.

Comment: Not quite. `if 0` does the same thing. See my answer for the reason.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, "if 1" literally tries to run the "1" command.  But the OP posted that as the analysis of the command.  Yes, to be precise the OP would have written "if [ 1 eq $? ]", but I understood the OP was trying to understand the exit codes and how they affect flow and was writing pseudo-code.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. But pseudo-code that looks exactly like valid bash code, but with the opposite meaning, is not the best way to express an idea.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Absolutely!  I removed my use of "valid-looking pseudo-code" in my answer, so as to not confuse future readers.  Thanks for keeping me straight. :)

Answer (score 1):

That snippet attempts to execute `1` as a command. Since you very probably don't have a command by that name, the condition is false. `if 0 ; then ...` would do the same thing (unless you happen to have commands named `0` or `1`).

If you want a condition that's always true, there are several options, the simplest of which is:

```
if : ; then
     ...
fi
```

or, if you prefer:

```
if true ; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Or `if true; then ...`.